# php website one page for design

Tags: php, model-view-controller, web, get, master-pages

I'm done creating a php website that has 6 pages, and the structure of the pages is the same for each one of them, the only thing that changes is the content, so is the same header, same design and same footer, the only thing that changes like I said before is the content itself.

so i was thinking instead of having many pages, I could have only one design page, and change only the content, what do you recommend?,and how do I do that?, also im not planning installing anything like Typo3, wordpress, joomla or whatever in my server, so I want something i could do using php idk. thank you!

Comment: how do I do that?, only one page desing and only change the content for differente links

Answer (score 3):

Simplest solution is to create separate files.

- header.php
- footer.php
- menu.php

In *header.php* put your code from header

```
<?php ?>
<HTML>
<HEAD>
</HEAD>
<BODY>
...
<? ?>
```

Same goes for footer and menu files.

Then you can use it by including them.

Your index.php could look like following.

```
<?php 
include("header.php");
include("menu.php");
?>

<h1> This is my content </h1>

<?php
include("footer.php");
?>
```

This is the easiest option I think for someone who doesn't want to spend using templates, CMS etc. Also you can create function called header that takes $title and changes title of your window. Up to you.

Comment: is it possible to do it backwards?, i mean include only the content and the rest static?

Comment: @Gmo It can be done both ways. You could use create one php file. (template.php), your design in there and then you can do content switching by "id". Ie. Do `switch($_GET['id']){ case 1: include("contact_us.php"); break; default: include("main_content.php"); break;}` It requires a bit more coding thats all. Other approach allows you to have different header for some pages though. For example when you have a small feedback page that you open up in separate window and it only has your logo. Or pages that are printer friendly with different header/footer.

Comment: @Gmo forgot to add to my previous comment. When you use approach with get you then call to different pages of you site with index.php?id=X Where X is your content number. Don't use include($_GET['id']) it will allow people read files on your host.

Comment: this sound good, but is it good to use it?, or would you recommend to stay with all the different pages?, also is it cool for search engines?

Comment: @Gmo Search engine wise I would recommend having separate pages. Simply because index.php?id=1 is harder to pick up than welcome.php or contactus.php. Also different titles or even keywords and descriptions in meta data would be good per each page. I personally use http://www.google.com/webmasters/#utm_medium=et&utm_source=us-en-et-bizsol-0-biz1-all&utm_campaign=en to check if my page is ok with search engine (Google). No I'm not working for google.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you want AJAX.  Use [prototype](http://www.prototypejs.org/).  You can make one page, and then use prototype to swap out the content (which could include a PHP page) based on user clicks.

Comment: I'm not going to downvote this, but this would be a very poor design choice.

Answer (score 0):

Simple and easy solution:

create footer.php and header.php

and in the header.php you can have something like this:

```
<?php function top_header($title) { ?>
    <html>
    <head>
    <title> <?php echo $title ?> </title>
    </head>
    <body>
<?php } ?>
```

footer.php

```
<?php function footer() { ?>
    </body>
    </html>
<?php } ?>
```

Your index.php could look this:

```
<?php
include("header.php");
include("footer.php");
top_header("Title of the page");
?>
Hello World!
<?php footer(); ?>
```