# How do I run PHP in HTML?

Tags: php, html, embed, embedding

If I have a file, file.php, in the same directory as index.html:

file.php:

```
<?php
echo "<body><img src=\"hi.jpg\" /><br /><p>I was here</p>"
?>
```

index.html:

```
<html>
<head></head>
<!-- I want to enter the PHP in file.php here --></body>
</html>
```

How do I put file.php in index.html?

Comment: This is very similar question to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6065494/php-website-one-page-for-design/6065573#6065573 and it has been answered.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Rename `index.html` to `index.php`, and fill it with the following:

```
<html>
<head></head>
<?php
require('./file.php');
?>
</html>
```

Comment: PHP can be run in .html files (both with mod_php and fpm), see comment below

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me:

Add the following to your .htaccess file

```
AddType application/x-httpd-php .php .htm .html
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php5 .html .php .htm
```

Comment: For whatever reason this makes Chrome want to download the webpage

Comment: It seems that the order matters, here is a working one:

`AddHandler application/x-httpd-php .htm .html`

`AddType application/x-httpd-php .htm .html`